# WKWebview evaluateJavaScript in swift only works on some websites

Tags: javascript, asp.net, swift

I am trying to fill in a login page with webView.evaluateJavaScript in swift. It works on some websites, but not others. The websites that it doesn't work on, I am able to type JavaScript in the chrome console with positive results, therefore I assume the JS is correct. Here is an example of what isn't working.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    guard let jsFile = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "injectCredentials", withExtension: "js") else {
        return
    }
    do {
        let injectJS = try String(contentsOf: jsFile)
        let formatted = String(format: injectJS, "NKuser", "NKpassword")
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(formatted) { (value, error) in
            print(value)
        }
    } catch {
    }
}
```

injectCredentials contents

```
var timeoutSeconds = 30;

var username = "%@";
var password = "%@";

var checkLogin = setInterval(checkLoginFields, 1000);
setTimeout(function() {
           clearInterval(checkLogin);
           }, timeoutSeconds * 1000);

function checkLoginFields() {
    var usernameInput = document.getElementById('ctl02_txtEmpNo');
    usernameInput.value = '123558';
}
```

and finally the webpage element.

it is a .aspx webpage. Typing the JS above into chrome console will enter text into the text field but in the iOS app, nothing happens. However that exact same code (with the element id changed) works on some other login web pages that aren't aspx.

```
<td style="text-align: left; padding-bottom: 3px;">
                <input name="ctl02$txtEmpNo" type="text" maxlength="6" size="20" id="ctl02_txtEmpNo" tabindex="1"><div style="visibility:hidden;display:inline-block;width:1px;overflow:hidden;"><input type="password" name="txtFakePassword" id="txtFakePassword" style="width:1px;"></div>
            </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

**evaluateJavaScript** only work for current page data, if you want to make some calls like want to evaluate login script what return it never return you value, so for catching login call back use. some other handler to see behavior of Login.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    if let url = webView.url, let host = url.host {
          if (url.path == loginPath) {
                if let username = self.username, let password = self.password {
                    let js = String(format: "js script", username, password)
                    webView.evaluateJavaScript(js, completionHandler: nil)
                }
            } else if (url.path == "error path") {
                // Login failed
            }
    }

}
```